# Disadvantage of Writing a Generic Stored Procedure to Get values from a Table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Are there any performance advantages or disadvantages of writing a stored procedure in a generic way?

For example I want to create a stored procedure `GetSampleModule` that returns the rows from the `Modules` table.

The stored procedure would either return `Modules` for a specific User or all users, based on the parameter provided.

Below is how I would write it:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE GetSampleModule
    @UserId   BIGINT = NULL,
    @ModuleId BIGINT
AS
BEGIN
    IF @UserId IS NOT NULL
        SELECT * 
        FROM [dbo].[Modules]
        WHERE [ModuleId] IN (SELECT [ModuleId] 
                             FROM [dbo].[ModuleAccess] 
                             WHERE [UserId] = @UserId);
    ELSE
        SELECT *
        FROM [dbo].[Modules]
        WHERE [ModuleId] = @ModuleId;
END;
```

Would it be better if it was written separately like below?

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE GetSampleUserModule
    @UserId BIGINT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM [dbo].[Modules]
    WHERE [ModuleId] IN (SELECT [ModuleId] 
                         FROM [dbo].[ModuleAccess] 
                         WHERE [UserId] = @UserId);
END;

CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE GetSampleAllModules
    @ModuleId BIGINT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM [dbo].[Modules]
    WHERE [ModuleId] = @ModuleId;
END;
```

The reason we came up with the "gGeneric" approach was to lessen the number of stored procedures to maintain and create, but we're unsure of the possible negative effects it may have. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: 1. Use an inner join rather than IN. 2. Use (@UserId is null or UserId = @UserId) as your condition to eliminate the IF.

Comment: @theMayer, the `OR` suggestion can result in suboptimal performance and parameter sniffing issues, unless the recompile query hint is specified (which has performance implications if the proc is frequently executed).

Comment: @DanGuzman, thanks for this. If you can put that as an answer i'd up vote it.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with select *, and duplication of code is always more problematic. I use this method regularly and my queries execute instantaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) is worth a read as it details considerations for complex search conditions. But with only 2 permutations, either of the methods in your question are acceptable solutions, IMHO.

I strongly suggest one avoid `SELECT *` regardless.